# Is it possible to retrieve the content of Qt Signals with a lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda, arguments, signals, pyside

I'm working on a PySide based App in which I continously get values and want to put them onto the GUI.
When I receive a value (I receive them via a CAN device using the PCANBasic library) I convert him to an int and emit him via the .emit() attributte of PySide.QtCore.Signal

```
Signal = PySide.QtCore.Signal(int)

# as soon as a new value is received and processed
Signal.emit(new_value)
```

Now I try to display my new_value on a PySide.QtGui.QSlider, thats what I do at the moment:

```
my_slider = PySide.QtGui.QSlider()
Signal.connect(change_slider_value)

# with a simple helper function
def change_slider_value(value):
    my_slider.setValue(value)
```

What I wanna do is:

```
Signal.connect(lambda value = data : my_slider.setValue(value))
```

With data being the what I emited with Signal (I'd love to somehow mark it, but the formating disappeaered on me and its my first post -.-)

When I test this I get the following Traceback:

```
self.calibrate.bar_val_signal.connect(lambda value = data: self.UI.calibrate.ctrl.Bar.setValue(value))  # self.change_bar_value)
NameError: global name 'data' is not defined
```

(You see the program is probably somewhat more complicated)
Translated to our pseudo code it would probably look like this:

```
  Signal.connect(lambda value = data: my_slider.setValue(value))  
  NameError: global name 'data' is not defined
```

In my opinion the issue is that the lambda function can't get the value out of the signal.
Has anybody a idea if there's a possibility to work without the need for a helper function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a lambda. Since your `change_slider_value` function only takes the argument that your signal would emit, you can just connect the signal to that.

```
Signal.connect(change_slider_value)
```

---

But as for why your lambda wasn't working, think of data as the parameter of a function. data will contain whatever the lambda is called with, therefore you could just do this, omitting 'value':

```
Signal.connect(lambda data: my_slider.setValue(data))
```

But I would suggest using the first solution, unless your parameters for `chang_slider_value` change.